# abrir gmail de google con asunto incluido

Tags: c#

Tengo este codigo, el cual abre la aplicacion que tengo por defecto para ver correo. le asigno el destinatario.

```
        private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "mailto:dany_lor97@hotmail.com?";
            proc.Start();
        }
```

Lo que quiero hacer y espero que me ayuden. es que se abra desde el gmail de google no de la lap (se como abrir la pagina de gmail, pero quiero que se abra con nuevo mensaje y con el destinatario puesto). o en otra cuestion que me pregunte donde quiero abrirlo siempre.

Comment: Solo por curiosidad, ¿cómo sabes que el usuario siempre va a tener una cuenta en Gmail?

Comment: poner un correo por defecto es solo para guiarme, lo que realmente hago es una consulta a SQL y coloco el correo en un linklabel. ya con la respuesta lo que se me ocurrio fue poner 2 botones y que s emuestren al apretar el linklabel y ya que eliga de esa manera si quiere abrirlo en la PC o en el Navegador.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vas a tener un poco complicado eso de abrir de frente de la página del Gmail pues se requiere autenticación en primer lugar. Considerando que hoy en día cada vez más usuarios tienen un cliente de correo tanto en el móvil como en la PC, optaría por realizar lo siguiente:

Reemplaza esto:

```
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "mailto:dany_lor97@hotmail.com?";
```

Por esto:

```
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "mailto:dany_lor97@hotmail.com?subject=titulo del nuevo mensaje";
```

Me parece que esto es lo que estás buscando:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?view=cm&fs=1&to=dany_lor97@hotmail.com&su=Aqui va el asunto&body=Contenido del mensaje");
```

Sigo pensando que deberías ir por la primera opción por efecto de libertad a usar cualquier proveedor de correo electrónico.

Comment: gracias bro. lo tendre en cuenta

Answer (score 0):

Mi codigo quedo de esta manera.no le coloco el asunto por que eso ya dependera de que se le quiera poner.

```
        private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e) //es el linklabel que almacena el correo de una persona
        {
            PC.Visible = true; //se vuelven visibles al usuario
            NV.Visible = true;
        }

        private void NV_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//abre el correo a el navegador
        {
            PC.Visible = false;
            NV.Visible = false;
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?view=cm&fs=1&to=" + correo.Text;
            proc.Start();
        }

        private void PC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//abre el correo con la app de la pc
        {
            PC.Visible = false;
            NV.Visible = false;
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "mailto:"+correo.Text+"?";
            proc.Start();
        }
```